# cmakelists importing external library leads to invalid or corrupted dll

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, static-libraries

I cannot figure out why the library cannot be linked into my project, any help will be appreciated.

Background: The external library provides a list of header files and library files and are put in a directory named "dll", files including "Elveflow64.aliases","Elveflow64.dll","Elveflow64.ini","Elveflow64.lib""Elveflow64.h","*.h","lvanlys.dll".

The codes I use in the CMakeLists file are shown as bellow:

```
SET("LIB_Elveflow_DIR" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dll)
include_directories(${LIB_Elveflow_DIR})
add_library(Elveflow64 SHARED IMPORTED) #${LIB_Elveflow_DIR}//Elveflow64.lib

set_property(TARGET Elveflow64 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIB_Elveflow_DIR}/Elveflow64.dll)
set_property(TARGET Elveflow64 PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${LIB_Elveflow_DIR}/Elveflow64.lib)
set_property(TARGET Elveflow64 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES ${LIB_Elveflow_DIR}/lvanlys.dll)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} Elveflow64)
```

However, when I run the code, The program has unexpectedly finished as Elveflow64.dll is missing.

Comment: As usual, on Windows `.dll` should be in the same directory with an executable (or under *system* directory).

Comment: Wow!Thank you so much.